# How to safely migrate hashed(bcrypt) passwords during a PHP Laravel system upgrade; from Laravel 8 to 10?

Tags: php, laravel-8, bcrypt, laravel-10

We're upgrading our PHP Laravel system, and one of the key concerns is the compatibility of passwords between the old and new systems. The passwords in the old system contain hashing function, and we need to ensure a smooth transition to the new hashing method without disrupting users' access. What would be the best way to handle this situation effectively in PHP Laravel?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tagged this with bcrypt which is a hashing function but your question mentions encryption. Which one is it?

Comment: Apologies its bcrypt

Comment: Encryption and Hashing are 2 different things... Are your passwords encrypted (bad) or hashed (good) in your database? Security concerns aside, if you keep the same value for `APP_KEY` in your `.env`, there shouldn't be any issues migrating Laravel 8.x to Laravel 10.x; that variable and it's usages have not changed between those versions (if at all really; I remember setting `APP_KEY` all the way back in Laravel 4.2)

Comment: If you are using bcrypt then I think verifying the password should still work because the hashed passwords are stored with additional data that have enough information to allow verification of even older hashes. Maybe newly added hashed passwords will use a different hashing function but you should still be able to verify the old ones as before.